# Widget as argument to command option of widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

I want to deactivate the button when user presses it. As there are lots of buttons in GUI that I'm making. I want to generalise this.
I am doing it the following:

```
def deactivate (btn):
   btn.configure(state='disabled')
   print ('Button is deactivated')
   return

Button = Tk.Button(root, text='click',command=lambda: deactivate (Button))
```

Above code is working fine for me, but nowhere I have seen anybody using this. So, I'm wondering, does this has complications going forward that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is fine.  But as you said there will be *a lot of buttons* having same feature, then I would suggest to create a custom Button class (inherited from `tk.Button`) to embed this feature and use this custom Button class for those buttons requiring this feature.

Below is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class MyButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kw):
        self._user_command = kw.pop("command", None)
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kw)
        self["command"] = self._on_click

    def _on_click(self):
        self.configure(state="disabled")
        if self._user_command:
            self._user_command(self)

def on_click(btn):
   print (f'Button "{btn["text"]}" is deactivated')

root = tk.Tk()

button1 = MyButton(root, text='click', command=on_click)
button1.pack()

button2 = MyButton(root, text='Hello', command=on_click)
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Note that I have changed the callback signature for `command` option. The instance of the button will be passed to callback as the first argument, so that you can do whatever you want on the button.